# How to Get JSON stringify data

Tags: asp.net, json

I Have a string `res = {"responseCode":"3001","response":"1533352091995"}`

how to select only `3001` from json? using asp.net

Answer (score 2):

Please find below answer:

```
string jsonData = @"{  
'responseCode':'3001',  
'response':'1533352091995'  
}";  

var details = JObject.Parse(jsonData);  
Console.WriteLine(details["responseCode"]);  

Console.ReadLine();
```